# How do I solve blurry font in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I just installed Ubuntu and I'm trying to use Lucida Sans across the system.
It looks fine everywhere except in the pages in the browser.
Is there any way to solve it?
Thank you

[Nptice the difference between page and elements in the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK8jF.png)

[Notice the difference between the document text and the address bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2VnJ.png)